# Why isn't my background image showing when I added it to CSS?

Tags: css, image

I tried to add an image in CSS to add to my project but when I put this in it does not show. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong for it not to show in the live server.
[image of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5a9e.png)

I tried background-image and I tried background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enter the path of the provided image relative to the folder where your CSS-file is. As an example.

1. `style.css` is located in your document root

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
```

2. Assuming your image.png is in a img subfolder at the same document root

```
body {
    background-image: url("img/image.png");
}
```